# Change default directory src for openwrt compiling package

Tags: makefile, package, openwrt

I'm creating a package for openwrt that contains several modules.
The package compiles right if the structure is:

```
package_name
. Makefile<s>.txt</s>
. files
. src
    + CMakeLists.txt
    + Module1
    + Module2
    + ...
    + Modulen
```

But if I change the name **src** by **modules** it shows me errors. I know the default structure search for src directory, but,
what should I add to my Makefile.txt to change default value src to any other one?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenWRt package structure [can be found here](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-developer/packages). The interresting part for you is `Bundle source code with OpenWrt Makefile`.

(I am afraid the `Makefile` should be just `Makefile` without `txt` extension. It would be helpful if you could post your complete Makefile - but I will try without it. Also please indicate the OpenWRT version you are using, the answer can be version-dependent)

I have found in `include/package-defaults.mk` the following [OpenWRT 19.07.1]:

```
Build/Patch:=$(Build/Patch/Default)
ifneq ($(strip $(PKG_UNPACK)),)
  define Build/Prepare/Default
        $(PKG_UNPACK)
        [ ! -d ./src/ ] || $(CP) ./src/. $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
        $(Build/Patch)
  endef
endif
```

This means to me, that either you:

- define `PKG_UNPACK` in your Makefile as follows: `PKG_UNPACK=$(CP) ./modules/. $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)`
- override default Prepare section as follows (or copy recursive, depending on your structure):

.

```
define Build/Prepare
        $(call Build/Prepare/Default)
        $(CP) ./modules/* $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/
endef
```

Comment: It solved the problem.
You were right, the Makefile is without .txt. It was an error writting the question.
I readed the document you attached about package, but I couldn't find the solution.
The scripting is very dense for me yet.

Comment: Did you choose defining the "PKG_UNPACK" or "overriding the Build/Prepare" ?

Comment: I defined PKG_UNPACK. The word override I don't like too much if I don't know the scope. But I wrote it as a comment.